# Setting up fail2ban to ban failed phpMyAdmin login attempts

Tags: security, logging, fail2ban

We've been using `fail2ban` to block failed `ssh` attempts. I would like to setup the same thing for phpMyAdmin as well.

As `phpMyAdmin` doesn't log authentication attempts to a file (that I know of), I'm unsure of how best to go about this.

Does a plugin / config exist that makes `phpMyAdmin` log authentication attempts to a file? Or is there some other place I should look for such an activity log?

Ideally I will be able to find a solution that involved modifying `fail2ban` config only, as I have to configure `fail2ban` with the same options on multiple servers, and would prefer not to also modify the various `phpMyAdmin` installations on said servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a combination of `.htaccess` and a simple `php` script to provide a solution I find acceptable:

**.htaccess**

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/fail2ban.php
```

**fail2ban.php**

- Detects presence of `$_REQUEST['pma_{username|password']`
- Validates `pma_{username|password}` against the `mysql`.`user` table
- Logs an error (format below) if the details are invalid

**Log format**

```
phpMyadmin login failed with username: root; ip: 192.168.1.50; url: http://somedomain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php
phpMyadmin login failed with username: ; ip: 192.168.1.50; url: http://192.168.1.48/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

This solution is suitable for me as I can easily integrate it into the `bash` script I've put together to smooth configuration of `fail2ban` across our servers.

Thanks to all who provided possible solutions!

As a follow-up, I have opened a question about issues I've run into creating a custom `fail2ban` filter to watch & act on this new log file: [Custom fail2ban Filter for phpMyadmin bruteforce attempts](https://serverfault.com/questions/435016/custom-fail2ban-filter).

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way (and in my opinion the less dangerous) to use phpMyAdmin is to not open phpMyAdmin directly on public IP but to listen only on internal IP or loopback and make a SSH tunnel to connect to it using a local port on the machine you want to work with phpMyAdmin. This way the sensible autentication is controlled by SSH (and already blocked by fail2ban).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that your suggestion is likely the most secure, but I'm not in a position where I can implement this right now. I'm interested in finding if there there is a way for me to use `fail2ban` to block bad access attempts to `phpMyAdmin` without modifying `phpMyAdmin` too much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have solved my problem in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

We protect phpmyadmin by adding apache htaccess ldap authentication (or file authentication) for the phpmyadmin location. You have to type the password twice, but failed login attempts are recognized by fail2ban.

[http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-apache-password-protect-directory-with-htaccess-file/][1]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have solved my problem in a different way.