# Custom fail2ban Filter for phpMyadmin bruteforce attempts

Tags: security, configuration, fail2ban

In my quest to block excessive failed `phpMyAdmin` login attempts with `fail2ban`, I've created a script that logs said failed attempts to a file: `/var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log`

---

**Custom log**

The format of the `/var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log` file is:

```
phpMyadmin login failed with username: root; ip: 192.168.1.50; url: http://somedomain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php
phpMyadmin login failed with username: ; ip: 192.168.1.50; url: http://192.168.1.48/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

**Custom filter**

```
[Definition]

# Count all bans in the logfile
failregex = phpMyadmin login failed with username: .*; ip: <HOST>;
```

**phpMyAdmin jail**

```
[phpmyadmin]

enabled  = true
port    = http,https
filter   = phpmyadmin
action   = sendmail-whois[name=HTTP]
logpath  = /var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

The `fail2ban` log contains:

```
2012-10-04 10:52:22,756 fail2ban.server : INFO   Stopping all jails
2012-10-04 10:52:23,091 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' stopped
2012-10-04 10:52:23,866 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'fail2ban' stopped
2012-10-04 10:52:23,994 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' stopped
2012-10-04 10:52:23,994 fail2ban.server : INFO   Exiting Fail2ban
2012-10-04 10:52:24,253 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.6
2012-10-04 10:52:24,253 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh'
2012-10-04 10:52:24,253 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' uses poller
2012-10-04 10:52:24,260 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2012-10-04 10:52:24,260 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 6
2012-10-04 10:52:24,261 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2012-10-04 10:52:24,261 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
2012-10-04 10:52:24,279 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh-iptables'
2012-10-04 10:52:24,279 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' uses poller
2012-10-04 10:52:24,279 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2012-10-04 10:52:24,280 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 5
2012-10-04 10:52:24,280 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2012-10-04 10:52:24,280 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
2012-10-04 10:52:24,287 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'fail2ban'
2012-10-04 10:52:24,287 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'fail2ban' uses poller
2012-10-04 10:52:24,287 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/fail2ban.log
2012-10-04 10:52:24,287 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 3
2012-10-04 10:52:24,288 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 604800
2012-10-04 10:52:24,288 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 604800
2012-10-04 10:52:24,292 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
2012-10-04 10:52:24,293 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' started
2012-10-04 10:52:24,297 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'fail2ban' started
```

When I issue:

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

`fail2ban` emails me to say `ssh` has restarted, but I receive no such email about my `phpmyadmin` jail. Repeated failed logins to `phpMyAdmin` does not cause an email to be sent.

Have I missed some critical setup? Is my filter's regular expression wrong?

---

### Update: added changes from default installation

Starting with a clean `fail2ban` installation:

cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

Change email address to my own, action to:

```
action = %(action_mwl)s
```

Append the following to `jail.local`

```
[phpmyadmin]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = phpmyadmin
action   = sendmail-whois[name=HTTP]
logpath  = /var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log
maxretry = 4
```

Add the following to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf`

```
# phpmyadmin configuration file
#
# Author: Michael Robinson
#

[Definition]

# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  regex to match the password failures messages in the logfile. The
#          host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>" can
#          be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)
# Values:  TEXT
#

# Count all bans in the logfile
failregex = phpMyadmin login failed with username: .*; ip: <HOST>;

# Option:  ignoreregex
# Notes.:  regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.
# Values:  TEXT
#

# Ignore our own bans, to keep our counts exact.
# In your config, name your jail 'fail2ban', or change this line!
ignoreregex =
```

Restart `fail2ban`

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

PS: I like eggs

Comment: It seems that it isn't picking up your new jail in the configuration. Please specify exactly which files you changed.

Comment: @mgorven I've update my question with a comprehensive overview of what I changed

Comment: Are these actual login attempts to your phpmyadmin instance or are they simply scanners *looking* for phpmyadmin?

Comment: I believe they're the latter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's fine but why not using the apache functionality to log failed logins ?

Add these lines to your Apache Config (i.e:/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf) in the according VirtualHost Section:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{userID}n %{userStatus}n" pma_combined
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log pma_combined
```

Then create the fail2ban filter:

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
[Definition]
denied = mysql-denied|allow-denied|root-denied|empty-denied
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*(?:%(denied)s)$
ignoreregex =
```

Now add the jail to /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[phpmyadmin]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = phpmyadmin
logpath = /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log
```

Restart apache and fail2ban:

```
service  apache2 reload
service fail2ban reload
```

and you are done, no need of php scripts so on..

Comment: Please don't edit directly `jail.conf`, create instead a copy `jail.local`

Comment: You are right @Simone, I modified my answer, thanks

Comment: I'm having a problem with the solution. Please see: http://serverfault.com/questions/815396/why-would-fail2ban-wont-work-with-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

1. You should change your script to include timestamp in log files. Without this, fail2ban will not work
2. use `fail2ban-regex /var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/phpmyadmin.conf` to verify your regex first.
3. I could start fail2ban successfully using your original configuration (prior to jail.local)

   ```
   Oct  7 00:42:07 hostname yum: Installed: python-inotify-0.9.1-1.el5.noarch 
   Oct  7 00:42:08 hostname yum: Installed: fail2ban-0.8.4-29.el5.noarch
   Oct  7 00:42:10 hostname yum: Installed: phpMyAdmin-2.11.11.3-2.el5.noarch
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to SYSLOG for Fail2ban v0.8.4
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'phpmyadmin'
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'phpmyadmin' uses Gamin
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 2
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh-iptables'
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' uses Gamin
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/secure
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 5
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'phpmyadmin' started
   Oct  7 01:01:03 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' started
   Oct  7 01:10:54 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'phpmyadmin' stopped
   Oct  7 01:10:55 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' stopped
   Oct  7 01:10:55 hostname fail2ban.server : INFO   Exiting Fail2ban
   Oct  7 01:10:56 hostname fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to SYSLOG for Fail2ban v0.8.4
   Oct  7 01:10:56 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'phpmyadmin'
   Oct  7 01:10:56 hostname fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'phpmyadmin' uses Gamin
   Oct  7 01:10:56 hostname fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log
   ```
4. Once correct regex are in place, you can use audit to see whether your file is accessed or not by fail2ban.

I used `auditctl -w /var/log/phpmyadmin_auth.log  -p warx -k phpmyadmin_fail2ban`

Comment: I'm having a problem with the solution, please see: http://serverfault.com/questions/815396/why-would-fail2ban-wont-work-with-phpmyadmin